# Reading an xml subtrees and the descendants C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, readxml

I have an XML file that contains several subTrees and those subtrees can also contain subtrees in them. something like this:

```
<File>
<A>...</A>
<B>...</B>
<C>
..
<D>..</D>
</C>
</File>
```

(The ".." are elements in the subtree). How can i read each subtree and then to reaad all its element (if this subtree containg a subtree i want to read it seperately and all his elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlReader` supports reading a subtree for that purpose; you can use the subtree-reader to as an input to other models (`XmlDocument`, `XElement`, etc) if you so wish:

```
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(source))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    reader.ReadStartElement(); // <File>
    while(reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subtree:");
        using(var subtree = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            while(subtree.Read())
                Console.WriteLine(subtree.NodeType + ": " + subtree.Name);
        }
        reader.Read();
    }
    reader.ReadEndElement(); // </File>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to read XML documents in .NET. For example to read the value of the `D` node:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var value = doc.Root.Element("C").Element("D").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with the following code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test.xml");
var DBID = doc.Root.Element("database").FirstAttribute.Name;
var DBIDValue = doc.Root.Element("database").FirstAttribute.Value;
```